# innerHTML with NodeJS and Jade

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to change the value of a number that is displayed with Jade from Javascript. I have a paragraph with id number, then get that in Javascript and try to change it using innerHTML, however nothing happens.

```
p#number 0
```

Above is how the paragraph is defined in jade.

Then I get the element in Javascript and attempt to change the value like so.

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");
number.innerHTML("1");
```

The object returned by document.getElementById is not null, however the .value() of that object is undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by `.value()`? You set a text inside a paragraph. There is no value that I could refere to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` isn't a function.

```
number.innerHTML = "1";
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't notice that. Even looked up a guide for using innerHTML because I thought I was doing something stupid. Thanks.